# Индексы MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Как устроены, в виде дерева?
Что из себя представляет некластерный индекс?

Comment: мало инфы в нэте разве?

Answer (score 2):

Кластерный индекс обеспечивает сортировку записей по полю, на котором он построен, в момент выборки. Не уверен, что физически это как-то влият на положение записей в базе, особенно с учетом того, что в наше время физическое расположение чего либо на диске - вещь весьма расплывчатая и относительная. А с учетом разных файловых систем или отсутствия таковых вопрос становится еще более сложным. Не стоит брать все это в голову: **главное, кластерный индекс обеспечивает сортировку при выборке.**

По большому счёту, всё зависит от того, какие запросы выполняются и, конечно же, от железа и `i/o filestream` и т.д.